# While using the ON Wooded area database, ArcGIS Pro is only performing spatial join for part of the dataset, how do I correct this?

Tags: arcgis-pro, spatial-join

I am using the wooded area data from Land Information Ontario I am running into trouble using the spatial join tool. I have my own KML file with polygons. I want to determine the closest wooded area to each polygon as well as which wooded areas exist within a 4km radius of the polygon. The spatial join is only working for part of the data/map. Several polygons are coming back with no matches/joins. There are clearly wooded areas nearby. I can't figure out why, I've tried with the downloaded wooded area file as well as the ArcGIS online option with little success. Does anyone know what the issue might be?

Comment: Are you using the KML file as your data layer, or did you convert it to a GIS format that supports geometry repair and spatial indexing?

Comment: Yes and I've changed them to the same coordinate system but I'm getting null values for all my join features.

Comment: How did you "change" them?  Assigning a new, incompatible CRS without reprojecting would cause joins to fail.

Comment: Using the project data management tool, is there a more appropriate way to do this?

Comment: Please [Edit] the Question to provide the coordinate reference and extent of the two layers which are not joining cleanly